# Are there any stand-alone C#/.NET Debuggers?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm wondering if there are any Visual Studio quality debuggers that can run outside of Visual Studio, instead of inside of the IDE?  It would be great if it were Open Source so I could check out how it was done, but that's not a requirement, neither is that be product free.

Comment: I'm wonder too whether here are any, but not the VS quality, it have an awful debugger, and that's the reason actually, that I am seeking for another.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163647/lightweight-net-debugger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinDBG with SOS extension

Following has series of 6 videos, to get started on WinDBG
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment

WinDBG is also useful for following scenarios, where VS debugger is not effective/available

1. Hangs
2. Crashes
3. Deadlocks
4. Production environment

Answer (score 4):

You should try [mdbg.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx).

Also available in the Windows SDK directory on your machine, like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools for VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite "standalone", but [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/) might have what you're looking for:

Answer (score 1):

You're not just looking for [DbgCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxbks7z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [GDB](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging) or the [Mono hard-debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aDebugger) with C#/.Net code.

Answer (score 0):

windbg

Its a bit of a pain for debugging managed code, but it can be done.